# Connect a websocket client in a docker container to a websocket server in host

Tags: docker, websocket

I have a websocket server running in my host, listening to port 8080.
In a docker container, I deployed a websocket client listening to the said server using this snippet:

```
connect_url="ws://0.0.0.0:80/"
```

and, exposing/mapping port 80 of the container to port 8080 of the host.

Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 80
```

When I ran the container:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 <name>
```

But I'm getting this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint : Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated.

Now I think this error is because the server in the host is already using port 8080, that's why it can't be mapped.

With these details given, I just wanted to know **how can my websocket client inside the docker container connect to the websocket server in the host**.

Comment: You are correct, the port's already bound to your server. Rather than open the container's port (80) to the host, you want to do the opposite. The best way to do this is to run the container with `--net=host` which shares the host's networking directly with the container.

Comment: I will try the --net=host you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: I already tried the --net=host. But the socket cannot connect to port 8080. I also changed the connect_url to ws://0.0.0.0:8080/

Comment: Yes, apologies, you'll need `8080` on the client to match the host's port. Did you try `127.0.0.1` rather than `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: I tried 127.0.01, but still no luck. I tried it when EXPOSE 8080 is present and not in the Docker file

Comment: Who's connecting to whom?  You say the host is already running a server; is the container running a server too, or is it just trying to launch a client to the host?  In which case you don't need `-p` or an EXPOSE setting at all, you just need to find the host's IP address and connect there (0.0.0.0 is not a valid outgoing IP address).

Answer (score 4):

I think problem is port 80 inside your container already in use, not 8080 on your host machine. Try to use another port for connect socket inside your docker container instead `80` (for example 777 port). Then run `docker run -p 8080:777 <name>`

By the way, check your host machine port already in user or not:

    `sudo lsof -i tcp:8080`

If not thing show up, that mean port `8080` not yet used. Incase already in use. Kill that process on port `8080`:

    `sudo kill -9 your_PID_ID`

Then try again

Comment: thank for your answer. Since the socket server in the host is running in port 8080, it's expected to be in use, and I can't kill it.. Because this is the port that my client (which is in docker container) will connect to. I'll try your other suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I tried this docker run -p 8080:777 <name>. Same error. port already in use

Comment: When you run `docker run -p 8080:80 <name>`. Your 8080 port will up and bind that port to 80 port inside container again... Your problem now is 8080 host machine port alredy in use, that clearly.

Comment: Or why you don't try another port on your machine. Some port like this : `docker run -p 999:80 <name>`